# How to preserve UV mapping when uptdating map texture

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

I've a GLTF model, I want to update its map texture but as soon as I do it, the new texture is displaying but the UV mapping of my model is not set anymore.

Is there a way to preserve the UV mapping when I load a new texture ? Here's the code I used to call a new map texture at some point in my website :

```
model.traverse(child => {
    if (
        child instanceof THREE.Mesh 
    ) {
        child.material.map = newTexture;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When replacing color textures of a glTF asset, you need these two lines.

```js
newTexture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding; // color textures must be marked as sRGB
newTexture.flipY = false; // honor glTF's uv convention
```

Comment: I'd like to also update the metalnessMap and the roughnessMap of my GLTF. I added the same two lines for these new textures but it's still not working. Should I add something else for updating correctly these textures ? Thank you very much

Comment: Both maps are no color textures so setting `THREE.sRGBEncoding` isn't right.

Comment: I tried to only apply the .flipY line on these textures but the issue remains. It looks like the UV mapping is erased. My metalnessMap/roughnessMap seems to apply to my whole mesh.